# How to use a list of characters and anchors in a BASH regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

From other regular expression engines, I'm used to being able to use a list of characters enclosed in brackets, such as /[0-3]/ to match 0 or 1 or 2 or 3, or /[,^]word/ to match word at the beginning of the string or immediately following a ",".  I haven't found documentation for BASH defining the syntax for how to do this with its regular expressions, and my testing hasn't provided a solution.  In the example below, I would expect BASH to print that foo, bar, and baz are all in "foo,bar,baz" and that quz is not in "foo,bar,baz".  But as you can see, that is not the output I am getting.

```
testString=foo,bar,baz
for myVal in foo bar baz quz; do 
  echo "Testing if $myVal is in $testString"
  if [[ $testString =~ [,^]$myVal[,$] ]]; then 
    echo "++$myVal is in $testString"
  else 
    echo "--$myVal is not in $testString"
  fi
done

##### output #####
Testing if foo is in foo,bar,baz
--foo is not in foo,bar,baz
Testing if bar is in foo,bar,baz
++bar is in foo,bar,baz
Testing if baz is in foo,bar,baz
--baz is not in foo,bar,baz
Testing if quz is in foo,bar,baz
--quz is not in foo,bar,baz
```

Comment: Use `if [[ $testString =~ (,|^)$myVal(,|$) ]]; then `

Comment: I don't know which regex engines you use, but I don't know any where `[,^]` would mean what you think it means ; to me, it's a character class matching either the `,` or `^` characters, `^` losing its usual meta-character meaning when it's found in a character class somewhere other than as its first characters.